# Is there a derivation (in English) of the Wien radiation law not based on statistics, other than that found in "Atomic Physics" by Max Born?

Tags: radiation

The textbook, "Atomic Physics", by Max Born contains a derivation in its appendix of the Wien radiation law that is based only on thermodynamics and Maxwell's laws of E&M.   The derivations I find today all start with Planck's radiation law and show agreement except at the ultra-violet end.  Born's text is old, and I wonder if students today are not puzzled by using Planck's law, which was not available to Wien at the time he offered his displacement law and his spectral energy density. Wien's original paper was no doubt in a German publication of record in his day.

Comment: Original paper:  Willy Wien, "Ueber die Energievertheilung im Emissionsspectrum eines schwarzen Körpers", *Annalen der Physik.* **63**, No. 294, 1896, pp. 662–669. Translated title: On the distribution of energy in the emission spectrum of a black body. English translation by J. Burke published as: Willy Wien, "XXX. On the division of energy in the emission-spectrum of a black body", *The London, Edinburgh, and Dublin Philosophical Magazine and Journal of Science*, **43**, no. 262 (March 1897), pp. 214-220. Interesting to note: Wien published using the colloquial version of first name Wilhelm.

Comment: French translation (in summary form?) by A. Cotton published as: W. WIEN. - "Ueber die Energievertheilung im Emissionsspectrum eines Schwarzen Körpers (Répartition de l'énergie dans le spectre d'un corps noir)". *Journal de Physique Théorique et Appliquée*, Volume 6, Numéro 1, 1897, pp. 318-319

Comment: I found a PDF with a scan of the English translation of Wien's paper from 1897 online. I am not linking it here because I am not sure it is legitimate copy. I am not a physicist and cannot tell with certainty whether Wien derived his "law" on the sole basis of Maxwell's work and thermodynamics, but it seems to me that he did.

Comment: Even with no knowledge of German, you could try to see if the equations in the paper of Wien somehow coincide with the equations in Born's book.

Comment: The derivation of Wien is based on statistical mechanics, specifically Maxwell's distribution for speed of molecules but does not use explicitly the first law of thermodynamics as in Born's book.

Comment: The derivation by Max Born of Stefan's and Wien's displacement laws is achieved by considering a black body enclosure with a movable, mirrored piston with the help of Maxwell's equations for the radiation pressure and the Doppler effect for the wave motion.  No statistics necessary. Born shows one can go further to get the spectral distribution by examining  dipoles in equilibrium with the radiation, since the  law has to be independent of the sort of oscillator or equilibrium could not be achieved.  The spectral law obtained is correct except at the ultraviolet limit.